# How to calculate the quality of comments using NLP

Tags: nlp, data-science

I'm new to data science. How can I calculate the quality of comments a user receives on their posts and assign ratings based on the comments' quality score in a dataset I'm analyzing as part of my data science work?

I've studied this, but NLP seems complex for beginners. Any suggestions for a simpler approach?

Comment: This is not the right forum to ask such a question but what do you mean by quality? grammar? good for business? or etc

Comment: As @Amir says, you first need to define what you mean by 'quality'. This is not an objective measurement. Once you have done that, you can see how this could be operationalised, ie calculated by a computer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! You're absolutely right, 'quality' can be vague in this context. I could use term effectiveness in place of quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `Sentiment Analysis` on each comment to determine sentiment (positive, negative, neutral), and assign scores accordingly. It's a simpler approach suitable for beginners. Look up resources to implement it easily. Is this helpful for your initial stage analysis.